# Detach debugger window in Xcode

Tags: xcode

How to detach debugger window so it be separate window ?

Comment: It already is a separate window for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Xcode>Preferences, select the General tab, and change the Layout. You have to close all projects before it will let you change this setting.

Comment: Also note that in that window there is a list of special clicks, such as "double click: opens in separate window".